# Verify if a category is the child of another category

Tags: php

Is there a way to verify if a category is child of another category? For example if I have clothes category and in that category I have t-shirts as sub-category. To do something like: is parent category clothes? Yes, so display text. I hope that you understand me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are two functions you can use:

For the default `category` taxonomy, you can use [`cat_is_ancestor_of()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/cat_is_ancestor_of/):

```php
// Retrieve category object by slug:
$parent_cat = get_category_by_slug( 'clothes' );  // term object
$child_cat  = get_category_by_slug( 't-shirts' ); // term object

/* Or retrieve category ID by name:
$parent_cat = get_cat_ID( 'Clothes' );  // term ID
$child_cat  = get_cat_ID( 'T-Shirts' ); // term ID
*/

if ( cat_is_ancestor_of( $parent_cat, $child_cat ) ) {
    echo 't-shirts is child of clothes';
}
```

For *custom taxonomies*, you would use [`term_is_ancestor_of()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/term_is_ancestor_of/):

```php
// Set the custom taxonomy's slug:
$taxonomy = 'my_taxonomy';

// Retrieve term object by slug:
$parent_cat = get_term_by( 'slug', 'clothes', $taxonomy );
$child_cat  = get_term_by( 'slug', 't-shirts', $taxonomy );
/* Or name, if you want:
$parent_cat = get_term_by( 'name', 'Clothes', $taxonomy );
$child_cat  = get_term_by( 'name', 'T-Shirts', $taxonomy );
*/

if ( term_is_ancestor_of( $parent_cat, $child_cat, $taxonomy ) ) {
    echo 't-shirts is child of clothes';
}
```

And note that `cat_is_ancestor_of()` is really a wrapper around (i.e. it uses) `term_is_ancestor_of()` which accepts either term ID or object, so for examples, you could do `cat_is_ancestor_of( 1, 2 )` and `term_is_ancestor_of( 3, 4, 'my_taxonomy' )` whereby the numbers like `1` and `3` are term IDs.

Comment: Used wordpress for 2+ years now... never knew those functions exist, always used `get_ancestors` to check if category is child of another. You lean something new every day =]

Comment: Glad my answer helped you and thanks for the upvote 